# Windows Live ID in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-live-id, windows-live

does anyone know is there a way to implement Windows Live ID authentication into your ASP.NET MVC site. There is some info about OpenID implementations and it uses some libraries.
So is there a way to implement Live ID or it is not yet supported.

Thank you

Comment: I'm curious why you'd implement Live ID and not something more flexible (like OpenID)?  What is the business logic behind such a decision?

Comment: Well the thing is that I want to enable users to use LiveID or OpenID, or nothing. I am not sure is it a good idea but it seems so, or is it possible.
And by the way there are 380 million users already using LiveID so I don't think it is a bad business decision.

Comment: I didn't mean to say nothing but without them using my own authentication. :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you would with Memberships:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/48857836-0c72-4efb-9d29-fbcb8e17ef3a/integrate-windows-live-id.aspx

Comment: Is this still the way to go in .net4, and mvc3? I'm looking for something more up to date.

Comment: @Maslow, If you use the ASP.NET MVC 3 Internet Application Template, you will get an Authentication Controller that uses Membership. Have a look at that. You could "change it", to adapt to Windows Live ID.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a valid business case, and I've gotten it to work with asp.net mvc.  I used the sdk sample code a posted by Filip and created a controller that handled auth response.  The only issue I had was during the windows live app verification process.  I couldn't get the verification process to work with the mvc site up.  I had to do the verification before I upload site.  See: [link text](http://forums.asp.net/t/1623751.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Newer information at

It's pretty independent of mvc or webforms I think.

Windows Live Messenger Connect Developer Guide
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx