# Live ID with MVC with out ASP.NET Membership

Tags: model-view-controller, authentication, live, windows-live-id, windows-live

Does anyone know is there a way to implement Windows Live ID authentication into your ASP.NET MVC site. I am moving a project from Web Forms to a MVC solution and do not want to rebuild the database so ASP.NET Membership mentioned in [windows-live-id-in-asp-net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373018/windows-live-id-in-asp-net-mvc) is not a valid solution.
And just to avoide this question the customer not want to use Open ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but here's an example of a MVC.NET app which uses LiveID but doesn't use an ASP.NET Membership provider:

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/actually-i-m-a-cia-agent