# ASP.NET MVC + LiveID --> should I use the Membership provider & Account controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-live-id

I'd like to use LiveID on an ASP.NET MVC site.  Should I still use the ASP.NET Membership provider?  How about the default MVC Account controller?  I have things working without either, but:

1. Using the Membership controller lets me see when a user last logged in.
2. Using the Account controller makes setting authentication cookies a bit easier.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[Answered here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373018/windows-live-id-in-asp-net-mvc), Peter Bromberg has a [nice sample](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/48857836-0c72-4efb-9d29-fbcb8e17ef3a/integrate-windows-live-id.aspx). You would still use the Membership provider albeit as a custom provider.